# Dedicated MySQL Server for Large Wordpress Site Memory Usage

Tags: linux, mysql, wordpress, memory-usage

### Preface

We are currently using Rackspace Cloudsites to host a very large WordPress Membership Content site using WishListMember. This setup is kind of slow for the price we pay for it, as Rackspace's MySQL and PHP performance is not great. I'm trying to convince the management to let me migrate it over to a SliceHost or Linode VPS so I can have more control over the setup.

### The Question

**How much RAM should our MySQL server have to host a large WordPress site?**

Assuming...

- That is the main use of the MySQL server.
- There are around 100-200 small pages. Very little regular posting.
- Betweeen 3,000 current regular users who are subscribed to the site (how much to scale this  up to 15,000?)
- A good caching plugin is installed an enabled.
- Most pages contain only 0-2kb of data each.

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps me out with this question.

Comment: Are you proposing to only move MySQL to another VPS provider and keep Apache/PHP with Rackspace? If so, that's a horrible idea.

Comment: How large is the MySQL database on disk?

Comment: No, I am proposing to rent two VPSs, one to run nginx/cherokee, and another to run the database server on in the same datacenter. The size of the database, if I am calculating it currently is 18.92681122mb.

Answer (score 1):

You've told us *nothing* about concurrent sessions, sql queries per second, network bandwidth, or any other relevant data to help us make a recommendation.

That said, Linode makes it *very* easy to upgrade plans. I'd recommend you start off with the 512. Unless you have a *very* busy site, I'd guess you'll find the 512 to be plenty. If it's not, upgrading to a larger plan is a couple clicks away, and only as much downtime as it takes to copy your disk images to another host.

(disclaimer: I've been a Linode customer for 7 years now, and have always been incredibly happy with their service)

Comment: If I knew the answers to those, and how to get them with CloudSites, I wouldn't be asking here, as I would know enough to get the answer myself.